# Sample syntax for NodeJS CloudFront createInvalidation

Tags: node.js, amazon-cloudfront

There seems scant examples of NodeJS AWS SDK.

Does anyone have some sample code to show how paramters should be formed for the [createInvalidation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFront.html#createInvalidation-property) method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation for the NodeJS implementation is available at docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFront.html

You can create an Invalidation as mentioned below.

```
var cloudfront = new AWS.CloudFront();
var params = {
  DistributionId: 'STRING_VALUE', // required
  InvalidationBatch: { // required
    CallerReference: 'STRING_VALUE', // required
    Paths: { // required
      Quantity: 0, // required
      Items: [
        'STRING_VALUE',
        // ... more items ...
      ]
    }
  }
};
cloudfront.createInvalidation(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

The details of the options and response is available at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFront.html#createInvalidation-property

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for answering this old question. I'd since switched to using a Grunt AWS library in this particular part of the project, but I'm sure this will help me next time I'm working in Node...